# Different screen size layout

Tags: android, screen, hdpi, mdpi

After reading [AndroidDev: Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), I still wondering on multi-screen support.

As document says:

- res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
- res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
- res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
- res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
- res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

I currently have such device support for development:

- 3.7" 480 x 800
- 4.0" 480 x 800
- 4.3" 480 x 800
- 4.3" 540 x 960
- 4.7" 720 x 1280
- 5.0" 1080 x 1920
- 7.0" 600 x 1024 (Tablet)

Can anybody help me to figure out what layout folder will my device matched ?

Comment: which device you used dear??

Comment: Several devices as I listed in my question...

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079588/setting-drawable-folder-to-use-for-different-resolutions/16080277#16080277) may help you.