# Tablet drawable folder for tablet

Tags: android, resolution

My designer has given images for different resolutions.
Hdpi,Mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi(only for phone).

Now when I started same app for tablet application. Designer has given another images.
for big screen.

So my question is,

Is there any different drawable folder name for tablet images?

I know the concept of ldpi,hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi but when there is 7" tablet with ldpi or mdpi then where should I put images. becaue I have already put phone images in drawable-ldpi/mdpi/hdpi,xhdpi.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079588/setting-drawable-folder-to-use-for-different-resolutions/16080277#16080277).

Answer (score 18):

For the 10-inch Tablets

> res/drawable-xlarge-mdpi/

for 7-inch Tablets

> res/drawable-large-mdpi/  or   res/drawable-large