# what are the android drawable folders i can get off?

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

I have **five** drawable folders in my android app:

**1.drawable-ldpi**

**2.drawable-mdpi**

**3.drawable-hdpi**

**4.drawable-xhdpi**

**5.drawable-xxhdpi**

and I have really large number of images withing my app, I want to know am i have to put all the images in all the folders? or can i abandon some of them? and also if there is a general way to add the images only once to my app.

*p.s. my app should run on tablets from 7' to 10' .*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079588/setting-drawable-folder-to-use-for-different-resolutions

Comment: dimension of device is not considered here....this is related to pixel density.

Comment: [screens_support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: thanks for all comments and answers, really helped me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use just drawable folder if you want to add images only once in your app. You need to add images to this mdpi, xhdpi, etc folders if You want use different images for each device dpi.

Answer (score 3):

Please see [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for how the android system loads resources.

In practice, if you do not want to support multiple screen sizes, you really only need one folder.

**drawable**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your app in different - different devices then yes you have to put your all images in all different folder.

For more reference check out this link 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

If you will add the HD images in **4.drawable-xhdpi 5.drawable-xxhdpi** Folder for Running App only in 7' to 10' TABLET then it will work Fine But you have to convert images in XHDPI & XXHDPI Resolutions as Well. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful if you want to remove some of the drawable folder. Low dpi devices could get OutOfMemory exceptions if the try to load big res images. One possible solution is to create several apks for your application where each one points to one or several screen types, in function of their dpi. To do this, you should use the next tags in your manifest. For example, to limit one of your apks to take into account only ldpi and mdpi devices:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

More info: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support multiple screens just one folder is enough.
otherwise convert your drawable images to each type of pixel density.