# drawable-sw720dp vs drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi and others

Tags: android

I want to provide drawables for:

- hvga and qvga phones (but those use hdpi drawables pretty well)
- hdpi phones
- xhdpi phones
- xxhdpi phones
- 7" tablets
- 10" tablets

I have folders:

- drawable-hdpi (used by phones up to 480x854 screens)
- drawable-xhdpi (used by phones like Galaxy S3)
- drawable-xxhdpi (used by phones like Galaxy S4)
- drawable-sw600dp (I would expect: used by 7" tablets)
- drawable-sw720dp (I would expect: used by 10" tablets)

**My original problem was, I thought resources from drawable-sw720dp are not used, but they are!**  Some graphic designer gave me files with different names and I did not notice. My fault.

So no problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original problem was, I thought resources from drawable-sw720dp are not used, but they are!

Answer (score 2):

For supporting tablets also, use `large`, `xlarge` qualifiers. `Nexus 7` is a large-hdpi tablet(technically it's `tvdpi`, but takes images from `hdpi`). So if you want to put images for `Nexus 7`, make a folder named `drawable-large-hdpi` and put the images there.

Now regarding the 10 inch tablets case, they are `xlarge` devices and their densities can change from `mdpi` to `xhdpi`(Nexus 10). But many have resolution of 1280 * 800 and they are `mdpi` devices.

Create drawable folder like this

```
// for Phones
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi

//for 7 inch tablets
drawable-large-mdpi
drawable-large-hdpi(for Nexus 7)

// for 10 inch tablets
drawable-xlarge-mdpi
drawable-xlarge-xhdpi(for nexus 10)
```

[***Source of answer***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079588/setting-drawable-folder-to-use-for-different-resolutions)

Comment: Thank you kaushik, your solution is perfectly fine, but I made a mistake. See edited question.