# Android Imageview is getting small

Tags: android

I am making an android application in which I am using an ImageView.My image is displaying perfectly on Normal phone screen,
but on big screen devices like Tabs, it is getting smaller and on the left side of the screen.So what is the most appropriate solution for the same?

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#550e8c" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#550e8c"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#e2ffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/help"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
            android:background="#550e8c"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/help1" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl"
        android:background="#E5E3E4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/home"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"

 />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="#781a8f"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/earthnew1"
            android:drawablePadding="30dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/aware_patient"
            android:textColor="#e2ffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCardiology_updates"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="#781a8f"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/updates1"
            android:drawablePadding="30dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Cardiology_updates"
            android:textColor="#e2ffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="#781a8f"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/linknew1"
            android:drawablePadding="30dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/useful_links"
            android:textColor="#e2ffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="#781a8f"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/linknew1"
            android:drawablePadding="30dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Useful_journlas"
            android:textColor="#e2ffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: u r using image hight and width wrap_content so thia resion use  hight and width fix like 50dp 50dp

Comment: I think you have to make image for 7 and 10 tab and put on respective drawable folder like sw600 and sw720.

Comment: the problem might be with resolution. Use a high resolution images and place in your xhdpi and xxhdpi drawable folder.

Comment: what resolution should i set for image to put it in xhdpi and xxhdpi folder

Comment: you need to create same image with different size and put all images in different folders as per its size.

Comment: which folder do you put your image file in? or you put the same size image in all drawable folders?

Comment: @vvv12 : create *home.png* for different resolution and placed those images in different `drawable` folder like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484020/drawable-sw720dp-vs-drawable-hdpi-drawable-xhdpi-and-others/26484473#26484473)

Comment: was putting same image in all drawable folders..

Comment: changed the resolution of image on nexus 7 image is getting displayed pefectly now the issue is with only one screen that is 10.1" WXGA tablet..

Comment: @vvv12 : check my answer hope that will help u :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used an image named *home* in `same resolution` for different `drawable` folder.

For supporting tablets also, use `large`, `xlarge` qualifiers. *Nexus 7* is a **large-hdpi** tablet(technically it's `tvdpi`, but takes images from `hdpi`). So if you want to put images for *Nexus 7*, make a folder named **drawable-large-hdpi** and put the images there.

Now regarding the 10 inch tablets case, they are `xlarge` devices and their densities can change from **mdpi to xhdpi(Nexus 10)**. But many have resolution of `1280 * 800` and they are `mdpi` devices.

Create drawable folder like this

> // for Phones
>
> 1. drawable-mdpi
> 2. drawable-hdpi
> 3. drawable-xhdpi
> 4. drawable-xxhdpi
>
> //for 7 inch tablets
>
> 1. drawable-large-ldpi
> 2. drawable-large-mdpi
> 3. drawable-large-hdpi(for Nexus 7)
>
> // for 10 inch tablets
>
> 1. drawable-xlarge-mdpi
> 2. drawable-xlarge-xhdpi(for nexus 10)

Create *home.png* for different resolution. Here is the list of `resolution` for whole screen slice your image according to your requirement

> 1. 320 X 480 for mdpi
> 2. 480 X 800 for hdpi, large-ldpi
> 3. 600 X 1024 for large-mdpi (7 inch tablet)
> 4. 720 X 1280 for xhdpi (s3, nexus 4)
> 5. 800 X 1280 for large-hdpi, xlarge-mdpi (nexus 7, other 10 inch
>      tablet)
> 6. 1080 X 1920 for xxhdpi (s4, s5, nexus 5)
> 7. 2560 X 1600 for xlarge-xhdpi (nexus 10)

Comment: i tried ur solution but problem is still on the 10.1" WXGA screen devices

Comment: have u create `drawable-xlarge-mdpi` folder and place an image respect to `800 X 1280` screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Image view inside the Linear Layout, evethough the imageview width is `wrap_content` the layout width is `fill_parent`. Change this as `wrap_content`...

**Like This**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl"
        android:background="#E5E3E4"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/home"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

issue is that you are putting same image in each folder. As Tablet and phone has different resolution you need different resolution image for them. If you using same image then you will face issue in one of the device.

Comment: right now my image resolution is 642*305..can u give me some idea what resolution is good to set it for tablet.. nd in which folder of drwabvle should i put it.?

Comment: you should have folders like drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi,drawable-xxxhdpi.                                                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079588/setting-drawable-folder-to-use-for-different-resolutions

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Linear layout and Image view with fill_parent or weight option , and use margin from left , right , bottom and top . so your image view and linear layout will expand according to your screen resolution .

Comment: 480*800 is the resolution for 7 in ch tablet.. and you can put your image in any drawable  folder , for better understanding user drwable_xhdpi folder

Comment: changed the resolution of image on nexus 7 image is getting displayed pefectly now the issue is with only one screen that is 10.1" WXGA tablet..