# which folder will give the tablet images android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-tablet-layout

In android we have hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi,

Which are all the folder will give the phone images and

Which are all the folder will give the tablet images.

Could any please help to understand?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16080277/3111083.

Comment: it's not about sizes. it's about the resolution of the device. the higher density then the more bigger image is needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward answer. Some tablets can be xhdpi, while others can be xhdpi depends on the size of the tablet (inches) 
check this website it might help you https://material.io/devices/